# Extracting values from character string

Tags: r, regex

I have a data frame which looks like this:

```
data.frame(puts = c("Put Daimler N JUN13 EUR 50 (24.06.2013)",
  "Put Daimler N SEP12 EUR 40.5 (24.09.2012)",
  "Put Wincor Nixdorf OCT14 CHF 43.80 (20.10.2"))
```

I need to extract the so called *strike prices* from each string.
That means I need to separate the numbers that are following the EUR and CHF currency description.

Unfortunately, the only constant in each string is that the prices are following either the EUR or CHF characters. So my idea was to extract the first numeric value after either "EUR" or "CHF" appears, but I completely faild to produce any presentable result.

The resulting data frame should look like this:

```
data.frame(puts = c("Put Daimler N JUN13 EUR 50 (24.06.2013)",
  "Put Daimler N SEP12 EUR 40.5 (24.09.2012)",
  "Put Wincor Nixdorf OCT14 EUR 43.80 (20.10.2"),
  strike = c(50, 40.5, 43.80))
```

Thanks for your help! Pat

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use `sub` function.

```
df <- data.frame(puts = c("Put Daimler N JUN13 EUR 50 (24.06.2013)",
                "Put Daimler N SEP12 EUR 40.5 (24.09.2012)",
                 "Put Wincor Nixdorf OCT14 CHF 43.80 (20.10.2"))
df$strike <- as.numeric(sub(".* (?:CHF|EUR) (\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?).*", "\\1",df$puts))
df
#                                             puts strike
#    1     Put Daimler N JUN13 EUR 50 (24.06.2013)     50
#    2   Put Daimler N SEP12 EUR 40.5 (24.09.2012)   40.5
#    3 Put Wincor Nixdorf OCT14 CHF 43.80 (20.10.2  43.80
```

**or**

```
df$strike <- as.numeric(str_extract(df$puts, perl(" (?:EUR|CHF)\\s*\\K\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?")))
```

`\\K` discards the previously matched characters from printing at the final. So here the previously matched `EUR` and `CHF` are discarded.

Comment: Very nice Avinash! Thanks a lot. I have to learn a lot about string manipulation. Can you recommend a tutorial on these types of tasks?

Comment: @Pat I learned a lot from this itself . But you may consider reading this http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Answer (score 0):

This is a another solution. Less clean than @Avinash but it works.

```
df<- data.frame(puts = c("Put Daimler N JUN13 EUR 50 (24.06.2013)",
                    "Put Daimler N SEP12 EUR 40.5 (24.09.2012)",
                    "Put Wincor Nixdorf OCT14 CHF 43.80 (20.10.2"),stringsAsFactors=F)
```

You split the line by " ", and then convert it to a matrix of numeric. All the elementes that cannot be coerced to numeric will be `NA`. Remove them, and you have reamining the `strike`

```
out.aux <- apply(df,2, function(x) strsplit(x, " "))
out.aux <- as.numeric(unlist(out.aux))
df$strike <- out.aux[!is.na(out.aux)]
rm(out.aux)

> df
                                         puts strike
1     Put Daimler N JUN13 EUR 50 (24.06.2013)   50.0
2   Put Daimler N SEP12 EUR 40.5 (24.09.2012)   40.5
3 Put Wincor Nixdorf OCT14 CHF 43.80 (20.10.2   43.8
```

Comment: What if the name of the company is `"Century 21"` or `"Studio 54"`? You are hoping that no other numbers appear in the string.

Comment: Yes, it would fail. The same as if there were more than one currency (EUR;CHF), with the other solution

Comment: The user clearly stated what the format is. The other solution does not have to account for a case that isn't in the data. Your solution on the other hand misses the specific request to match the numbers after the currency abbreviation.

Comment: I agree with Pierre. But thank you Vincent for your help!